# How to interface with obd ii elm327?

Tags: iphone, ipad, obd-ii

Do I have to purchase [this](http://standards.sae.org/j1939_201206/) in order to get all the PIDs and the full instruction set for communicating with the car's obd ii interface via an ELM327? I tried looking for some kind of api for the ELM327 connector, but couldn't find any documentation besides the actual chip's schematics.

The standards linked above seem to provide the instruction set for all current obd2 protocols, can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to mess with it a bit, but I need a device to test on and I don't have one right now.
Here's a github repo that has an ELM327 library on it
https://github.com/FuzzyLuke/OBD2Kit

And here's the OBD2 codes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_OBD-II_Codes

Let me know if you have any luck getting it to work.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There's a high chance if you Google on the name of the file, you find the document.

The wikipedia version is very much complete for the OBD-II standard.

Here are the AT (ELM specific commands, for the ELM327 chip):
http://elmelectronics.com/ELM327/AT_Commands.pdf